# Configuring VSFTPD for a webserver

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I've been able to install VSFTPD on Ubuntu Server 14.04.1 .. But now, I'm having an issue configuring it ... The server is running as a Web Server, so FTP is essential to update the website every now and then. These are the info that I need to know how to configure.

First, I will create a user called `ftpuser` and will give it a password.

```
sudo adduser ftpuser
sudo passwd ftpuser
```

From here, I'm stuck. No online tutorial was able to provide me with what I need to achieve.

I need the user `ftpuser` to access `/etc/www/html` folder to be able to upload new files. How can I achieve this?

- How can I secure the FTP from brute force attacks?
- Can I limit it to a specific IP/Subnet?
- Can I force the user to use a SSL Certificate to connect? If so, is it generatable from the server?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94603/vsftpd-limit-ftp-access-only-to-var-www) for your main question.

To change what directory the FTP user can access, just make sure that you set `chroot_local_user=YES` and then run `usermod --home /etc/www/html ftpuser` to set the user's home directory. Make sure that the user is in the right groups to access anything they need to there.

> How can I secure the FTP from brute force attacks?

**Use a secure password.** Also, your next questions will help.

You can also look into tools like [fail2ban](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fail2ban).

> Can I limit it to a specific IP/Subnet?

Best way is probably to use [iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo).

> Can I force the user to use a SSL Certificate to connect? If so, is it generatable from the server?

Yes, the [Ubuntu guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/vsftpd) describes setting up SSL.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I've followed your guide and FTPUser was able to login to the folder, but was unable to create a directory. I tried permissions 755 and 775 both not working  .. need help.

Comment: Edit the permissions of the folder into your question.

Comment: if you are referencing to chmod, it didn't work

Comment: can you help here?